# If $m \equiv m'$ mod $n$, then gcd$(m,n) = 1$ $\Longleftrightarrow$ gcd$(m',n) = 1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How to prove the following statement:

If $m \equiv m'$ mod $n$, then gcd$(m,n) = 1$ $\Longleftrightarrow$ gcd$(m',n) = 1$.

I have never learned number theory before, for me it's already hard to prove g.c.d of two integers is 1, not to mention the whole statement above.

These kinds of facts jump out frequently in my abstract algebra course. Is there any good introductory number theory book that has **clear** and **illuminating** proof for these "basic" facts? Then I can remember the proof technique and these "basic" results by rote.

Comment: Your question has a similar answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/381310/proving-n-equiv-p-k-longleftrightarrow-gcdp-k-gcdn-k?rq=1

Comment: @Valerin I got it! Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the problem has a simple solution, if you are allowed to use the following result:

$$\ gcd(m,n)=1\ \mathrm{iff}\ \exists k_1,k_2\in\mathbb{Z}\ \mathrm{such\ that}\ k_1m+k_2n=1 $$
since $m\equiv m'(\mod n)$ then $m=m'+k_3n$ for some $k_3\in\mathbb{Z}$ replacing we have
$$1=k_1m+k_2n= k_1(m'+k_3n)+k_2n=k_1m'+(k_2+k_3)n $$
which shows that $$ gcd(m',n)=1$$

You can try the other way.

Comment: Thanks! A very simple answer for me.